# How to determine applications whose application master ran on current node in YARN?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, resourcemanager

Suppose I have a program running on given node in cluster, in that program is it possible to get list of applications whose application master ran on current node?

One way I could figure out till now is by querying RM REST API from the program and getting applications list and comparing 'amHostAddress' with the current node address but I want to avoid polling RM API. I am looking for a way in which I can get this information locally without contacting master node.

Can anyone help me please?